# Show Excerpts In Twenty Eleven Theme

Tags: excerpt, theme-twenty-eleven

I just need to create a blog I have done everything i guess, its showing posts but they are supposed to be kind of summary first and after click the whole post.

I already selected the "For each article in a feed, show summary" from reading option from dashboard

I already activated the hidden option of enabling excerpt, and typed some words to check but no luck..

I have replaced the `<?php the_content();?>` to `<?php the_excerpt();?>`

Might be i am missing something, it was simple every site I followed for the solution they told me so but i am not getting  output

theme i am using is Twentyeleven and I dont want to use any plugin coz they(You and all word-press masters)say its simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show excerpts on home page and all archive pages, open `content.php` and modify the following line:

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```